# Android: How to make square 1:1 widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to make a squaere widget.

My Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/rounded_conners"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn03_off" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I can make ImageButton to be square. Thanks to square image in scr, but what I need a backgroundImageView to be square layout (aspect ratio 1:1) and there is my shape which is not square.

Comment: make the image view square by subclassing the imageview and calling teh onmeasure() in it

Comment: You are right, AppWidgets can't exploit custom views. I'am Sorry

Comment: And that's the problem which I can't solve...

Comment: Why you don't set make square programatically, calling `setWidth` and `setHeight` with same values? Have you tried it?

Comment: The widget is "expandable" so user actually can change its dimension on the screen.. So I don't know specific dimension unfortunately. And I'm not sure if I can use set Width and Height in widget